# Ошибка: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 404. Description: Not Found при запуске. 24 и 26 строка, send неразрешенная ссылка

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

import klava
import oplat
bot = telebot.TeleBot('Token')


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start", "help"])
async def start(message):
    markup_one = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('произвести оплату')
    markup_one.row(btn1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет!', reply_markup=markup_one)
    silka, payment = oplat.create_oplata()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ссылка на оплату', reply_markup=klava.oplata(silka, payment))


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
async def proverka(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    if call.message.text == 'ссылка на оплату':
        otvet = oplat.oplata_chek(call.data)
        if otvet:
            await bot.send.message(chat_id=call.from_user.id, text='Платёж прошёл успешно')
        else:
            await bot.send.message(chat_id=call.from_user.id, text='Платёж не прошёл')


while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)